# Insert multiple array object into another array randomly not mixing elements of any single array object elements

Tags: php, arrays, php-5.3, laravel-4.2

Assume that having 3 array object: $main, $one, $two

How to Insert multiple array object into another array randomly not mixing elements of any single array object elements

```
$main = (1,2,3,4,5);

$one = ("orange", "apple");

$two = ("car", "bus", "train");
```

I need to insert array object elements **'$one'** and **'$two'** in random position of array **'$main'** with whole set of both array object elements without mixing.

**Resulting array:**

```
 $result = (1, 2, "orange", "apple", 3, 4, "car", "bus", "train", 5);
```

Please comments if you are not getting my question. This would be a great help if answered.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Do you want to merge those arrays in one in random orders ?

Comment: yes, i want to insert arrays **$one** and **$two** in random index of ** $main** but $one and $two as a whole individual sets

Answer (score 0):

```
$main = array_merge($main, $one, $two);
shuffle($main);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.